# Проверка на "дурака" с возвратом a=int(a) python

Tags: python, проверка

Есть конструкция:

```
while True:
try:
    a = input("Введите ваш возраст: ")
    if int(a) < 18:
        print("Доступ запрещен.")
        break
    elif int(a) >= 18:
        print("Доступ разрешен.")
        break
    else:
        raise ValueError
except ValueError:
    continue
```

Как можно преобразовать эту штуку таким образом, чтобы в try не прописывать постоянно int(a) для сравнения чисел. Да и вообще для любых операций?
Или подойдет такая тема:

```
while True:
    a = input("Введите возраст: ")
    if not a.isnumeric():
        continue
    else:
        a = int(a)
        break

if a < 18:
    print("Доступ запрещен.")
elif a >= 18:
    print("Доступ разрешен.")
```

Comment: Чем не устраивает try?

Comment: Как говорил мой препод: "За `break` ставлю 2"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может, Вам подойдёт такой способ?:

```py
while True:
    try:
        age = int(input('Введите ваш возраст: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        continue

if age < 18:
    print('Доступ запрещен.')
else:
    print('Доступ разрешен.')
```

Answer (score 0):

У тебя ветка else в первом примере никогда не сработает. Если строка из стандартного ввода окажется неприводимой к типу int, то возникнет ValueError, который ты уже обрабатываешь.
Для того, чтобы проверить, можно ли привести к int , строку из стандартного ввода, можешь проверить её

```
age = input()
if age.isdigit():
    age = int(age)
else:
    # some actions
```

Comment: А как она не сработает, если она работает? И если скопировать первый вариант кода, то он полностью рабочим окажется. А если при запросе возраста ввести букву или дробь, то программа заново запросит возраст.

Comment: Понимаешь, что if и elif покрывает полное множество всех исходов. Твой else насколько я понял, рассчитан на то, что возраст не приводится к int, но в таком случае твой код просто сломается на ValueError, который ты перехватываешь в блоке except.